# A basic measure theory question on Stochastic Process

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(Ω, F, P)$ be a probability space, $T$ some index
set, and $(S, Σ)$ a measurable space. $X : T × Ω → S$ is a
stochastic process, so it is measurable map. Let $S^T$ be the collection of all functions
from $T$ into $S$. I don't understand why $Φ_X : Ω → S^T$, defined by $Φ_X(\omega)(t) = X_t(\omega)$ is a measurable map. Is Fubini's theorem of help here.

Comment: You need to specify a sigma-algebra on $S^T$ in order to talk about measurability. Also, you probably mean $\Phi_X(\omega)=(t\mapsto X_t(\omega))$.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Yeah, it is the product sigma algebra. I got the answer. It is trivial